# VBScript Converting Object to String?

Tags: vbscript

SORRY IF THIS IS CONSIDERED A REPOST, I DID DELETE THIS FROM THE PROGRAMMER STACK.

I am usually a silent user of this website.  Picking bits and pieces of your code to better educate myself on the different ways of programming things.

I have run into a wall with VBScript, and I'm not sure how to word my issue.

I am trying to write the IP addresses of a computer (all of them) to a text file.

If you run the code below, it will output your computer's IP addresses (ipv6 and ipv4, or whatever you have active).

I want this to be written to a text file, but when I use a `Scripting.FileSystemObject`

```
Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(CurrentDirectory & "\" & SN.SerialNumber & ".txt",2,true)
```

I cannot simply do

```
objFileToWrite(strIP)
```

Any thoughts? This is still a work in progress, so I know my code is sloppy, so please be nice on that.  This is kind of a mashup of 3-4 different code sources, and I have little idea of how VBScript works yet.  I am trying to learn though!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'************Where I left off.  Issue is converting object to String?
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://./root/CIMV2" )
Set colItems      = objWMIService.ExecQuery( strQuery, "WQL", 48 )

For Each objItem In colItems
    If IsArray( objItem.IPAddress ) Then
        If UBound( objItem.IPAddress ) = 0 Then
            strIP = "IP Address: " & objItem.IPAddress(0)
        Else
            strIP = "IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses: " & vbCrLf & Join(objItem.IPAddress, vbCrLf )
        End If
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo(strIP)
```

Update: @Noodles [Apparently I don't have enough Rep to add pics?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lpXm.png)

Comment: `objFileToWrite.writeline objItem.IPAddress(0)`

Comment: @Noodles Unsuccessful.  Attaching error as an edit.

Comment: @BillyKleinhomer please don't post errors as images instead use a simple blockquote `>` see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: The point was you use the WriteLine method to write out the property of an object (not the object itself). Help is here https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

Comment: @Noodles UGH, thank you! I can't believe I missed that.  That is exactly what I was leaving off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: @Noodles for credit.  Stupid mistake on my part.

I figured it out I guess.  I am not sure why it wasn't working last night (probably because I was trying to do this at 2 am)  But here is the working block of code I have.

Sorry to waste your time guys, thanks for the input!

```
winmgmt1 = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//" & ""
'WScript.Echo winmgmt1
Set SNSet = GetObject( winmgmt1 ).InstancesOf ("Win32_BIOS")

dim WMI:  set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
dim Nads: set Nads = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter where physicaladapter=true")
dim nad
dim strIP



'This is to grab the Directory of this script.  It is stored in "CurrentDirectory"
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim CurrentDirectory
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

' Text box output.
for each SN in SNSet
     MsgBox "Your serial number is: " & SN.SerialNumber & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "SN saved to: " & CurrentDirectory & "\Computers by Sn\" & SN.SerialNumber & ".txt"

' Creates file.
Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(CurrentDirectory & "\Computers by SN\" & SN.SerialNumber & ".txt",2,true)

' Writes serial number to text file.
objFileToWrite.WriteLine("Your serial number is: " & SN.SerialNumber)
objFileToWrite.WriteLine("")


'*************************** Convert WScript to String?
Dim WshNetwork
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
dim ComputerName
ComputerName = WshNetwork.ComputerName
'dim compName: set compName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'objFileToWrite("Computer Name: " & ComputerName)
'objFileToWrite(WshNetwork.ComputerName) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Not working.  Tried CType(ComputerName, String)
'*************************** Not working properly.  Needs to be in text file rather than Echo

' Writes MAC address to text file.
for each Nad in Nads
    if not isnull(Nad.MACAddress) then objFileToWrite.WriteLine(Nad.description & ":   " & Nad.MACAddress)
next

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE MACAddress > ''"

'***********************************Where I left off.  Issue is converting object to String
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://./root/CIMV2" )
Set colItems      = objWMIService.ExecQuery( strQuery, "WQL", 48 )

For Each objItem In colItems
    If IsArray( objItem.IPAddress ) Then
        If UBound( objItem.IPAddress ) = 0 Then
            strIP = "IP Address: " & objItem.IPAddress(0)
        Else
            strIP = "IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses: " & vbCrLf & Join(objItem.IPAddress, vbCrLf )
        End If
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo(strIP)
objFileToWrite.WriteLine(strIP)
'test = CType(strIP, String)
'objFileToWrite(test)
'***********************************Where I left off.

' Closes text file. 
objFileToWrite.Close
Set objFileToWrite = Nothing

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The VBScript TextFile object's default method isn't WriteLine.  I would also avoid your object creation/method chain and create each object via a `Set` before calling methods on it:

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFileToWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt",2,true)
objFileToWrite.WriteLine("Information to write - i.e. the IP address")
objFileToWrite.WriteLine()
objFileToWrite.Close
```